# PHP: Incremental list using SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I'm working on a simple shopping cart, I'm able to output a single form result (POST), but I have no idea how to incrementaly add lines to newer items when the user comes back to the form and adds items (they are currently being overriden).

Here's what I currenly have:

```
       <?php

session_start();

//Getting the list
$list[]= $_SESSION['list'];


$_SESSION['list'] = array(
'item' => $item, 
'quantity' => $quantity,
'price' => $price);

//list
echo  "<b>SHOPPING CART</b></br>";


echo "1. ".$_SESSION['list']['item']." ".$_SESSION['list']['quantity']." units".", ".$_SESSION['list']['price']." USD.";

//Returning list
$_SESSION['list'] = $list;


?>
```

A sample of the current output is:

```
    SHOPPING CART
1. Banana 3 units, 2 USD.
```

The ideal output should be something like this:

```
    SHOPPING LIST
1. Banana 3 units, 2 USD.
2. Coffe 4 units, 6 USD.
3. Etc
and infinte...
```

Answer (score 4):

Let it be a multi-dimensional array:

```
//add an element to the list
$_SESSION['list'][] = array(
  'item' => $item, 
  'quantity' => $quantity,
  'price' => $price),
);
```

Then use [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) to loop over it:

```
foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $item) {
  echo $key, '. ', $item['item'], ' ', $item['quantity'], ' units';
}
```

Comment: Hi, Emil, your example is working but It's only showing the first letter of each value. Take a looK:
item. C C unitsquantity. 4 4 unitsprice. units

Comment: Instead of Coffe it says C. By the way how can the list be incrementented? For example 1., 2., 3, as I explained above. Thanks!